# accept(...) seems to be modifying the file descriptor parameter I give it

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking

Here's a section of my code, for a simple echo server I'm attempting to write using the linux sockets syscalls:

```
while (true) {
    std::cout << "Fd before accept: " << fd << std::endl;
    if ((current_socket = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) {
        std::perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "Accepted (fd) = " << fd << std::endl;

    amount_read = read(current_socket, in_buf, 1024);
    std::cout << "Amount read: " << amount_read << std::endl;
    std::cout << "In from client: " << in_buf << std::endl;
    std::cout << "What would you like to say back: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, out_buf);
    send(current_socket, out_buf.c_str(), out_buf.length(), 0);
    std::cout << "Sent." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "fd before looping = " << fd << std::endl;
}
```

Just before this piece of code, I set up a socket descriptor `fd`, and then, immediately before the while loop begins:

```
listen(fd, 4);
```

I compile this and then run it, and then run a client program which I've written to send a message (`"Hello from the client"`) to the server.

## My problem

Anyway, my problem with this is that, as the title suggests, the call to `accept(...)` is modifying the value of `fd`. First of all, I can't understand how this is *possible* - `fd` isn't being passed as a pointer, so how could it possibly be modified by a function call? But this point is mainly just of interest - the main implication of this problem is described in the next section.

I'm certain the value of `fd` has been changed because here's some sample output from the server:

```
Attempting to listen
Listening
Fd before accept: 3
Accepted (fd) = 0
Amount read: 17
In from client: Hello from client
What would you like to say back: ?
Sent.
fd before looping = 0
Fd before accept: 0
accept: Socket operation on non-socket
```

So as you can see, `fd` before the call to accept is *3*, but then after the call it becomes `0`.

## Why this is a problem

Referring back to the output from the server, as shown above:

```
accept: Socket operation on non-socket
```

Which clearly is as a result of the new value of `fd` not being a valid socket.

## What I've tried

Enveloping also the `listen(...)` call in the `while(true) {...}` loop, just in case I need to listen again for each client. I doubted this would work, and it didn't. I'm all out of ideas.

## Other questions which haven't helped

I found a question somewhere asking why `accept(...)` was *returning* (**not** changing the `fd` parameter) a value of 0. I understand from that that 0 is a valid socket descriptor, but clearly here it isn't. Also, this just shouldn't be happening, right?

## My question

Just to sum up: why is `accept(...)` modifying one of its non-pointer parameters, and how can I fix this?

## Full code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int create_socket(uint16_t port, struct sockaddr_in* addr) {
    int server_fd;
    int opt = 1;

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        std::perror("Socket create failed.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        std::perror("setsockopt failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr->sin_port = htons(port);

    // now bind it to a port
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)addr, sizeof(*addr)) < 0) {
        std::perror("bind failed");
    }

    return server_fd;
}

int serve(int fd, struct sockaddr_in* addr, int backlog=4) {
    std::string to_send;
    int addrlen = sizeof(*addr), amount_read;
    int current_socket;
    char in_buf[1024];
    std::string out_buf;

    std::cout << "Attempting to listen" << std::endl;
    if (listen(fd, backlog) < 0) {
        std::perror("listen failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::cout << "Listening" << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Fd before accept: " << fd << std::endl;
        if ((current_socket = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) {
            std::perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        std::cout << "Accepted (fd) = " << fd << std::endl;

        amount_read = read(current_socket, in_buf, 1024);
        std::cout << "Amount read: " << amount_read << std::endl;
        std::cout << "In from client: " << in_buf << std::endl;
        std::cout << "What would you like to say back: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, out_buf);
        send(current_socket, out_buf.c_str(), out_buf.length(), 0);
        std::cout << "Sent." << std::endl;

        std::cout << "fd before looping = " << fd << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int fd = create_socket(5555, &addr);

    serve(fd, &addr);

    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: How do you create socket fd? I don't see this code...

Comment: There is no way `accept` can modify a value of an int passed to it in **correct** program. If what you are saying is true, it means there is undefined behavior in your program, somewhere.

Comment: The fact that you are reinterpret_casting `addrlen` suggests to me that perhaps you are allocating a value of the wrong size for it, which would lead to `listen()` doing a buffer overrun on it.

Comment: @Sandro Please see the edit - I've added the full code

Comment: @SergeyA I've attached the full code - I'm failing to identify any undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, as expected.

```
int addrlen = sizeof(*addr), amount_read;
...
accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen));
```

First off, you are taking address of `addr`, which is already a pointer. You should not do this.

Also, my little crystal ball tells me you are on 64 bit platform, and as such, your `socklen_t` is a 64bit integer.

To fix your problems, do not take address of the pointer and do away with nasty cast and use the proper type.

```
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(*addr);
...
accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*)addr, &addrlen);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't fix my problem. I get the exact same issue when I make this change.

Comment: @JacobGarby, yes, you have two bugs - you are also taking address of addr, while it is already a pointer, when providing argument to accept. See my latest edit.

Comment: Yep, that did it! I'm kicking myself for having not seen that - thanks!